# c# TimeZoneInfo serialization

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, timezone

I'm have a bit of a problem with serializing TimeZoneInfo object. I was trying to use TimeZoneInfo variable in data contract for WCF service but the serialization was failing. So i wrote this little piece of code to test the serialization. Here's a what i do:

```
        var fileName = "tmp.xml";
        var tz = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
        var dataSer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(TimeZoneInfo));

        try
        {
            using (var xml = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
            {
                dataSer.WriteObject(xml, tz);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```

Now, when i call WriteObject method it throws an exception:

> Type 'System.TimeZoneInfo+AdjustmentRule[]' with data contract name 'ArrayOfTimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System' is not expected. Consider using a DataContractResolver or add any types not known statically to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding them to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.

If i attempt to add
[KnownType(typeof(System.TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule[]))] to the class i get the same error. And if i add this line to my data contract interface i get compile error:

> Error  1 'System.TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule' is inaccessible due to its protection level

And according to the documentation TimeZoneInfo class implements ISerializable so it should serialize by default.

Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong here? I would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure why it doesn't just serialize simply, but have you considered just serializing the [ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.id.aspx)? That's likely to be rather more efficient - and simpler! - than serializing all the information inside, and should be fine so long as both systems have that time zone.

EDIT: Note that this won't work with custom time zones, for which you should look at `ToSerializedString` as noted elsewhere.

Comment: Yeah, i mean as a work around i would have to do something of that sort. But i would like to have the variable strong typed and in general i'm kind of mystified as to why this doesn't work. What's the point of the class being ISerializable if i can't serialize it?

Comment: @RedOctober: I don't know - that does seem odd. I don't know enough about WCF to know whether DataContractSerializer uses the same format as the normal BinarySerializer which is I *believe* what ISerializable is about. Note that if you serialize just the ID, then when you fetch the time zone again you'll get the most up-to-date information from the operating system, rather than just what was known at the time of serialization. Whether this is a good thing or not depends on your exact situation, of course.

Comment: 1. The behavior looks like a bug in framework. 
2. ID wouldn't be enough when you get custom timezone. I used ToSerializedString method as workaround. ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.toserializedstring(v=vs.100).aspx )

Comment: @PuterdoBorato: True, but I doubt that most programs are going to use custom time zones, are they? (I should have mentioned that though.)

Comment: @JonSkeet You are right on the ISerializable being the BinarySerializer, not the DataContractSerializer.  These types are not fully supported by WCF out of the box.  You can convert to string as you state or send across a customer object containing a DateTime and and Offset (in seconds).  This might have issues for clients with WSDL access if they do not properly account for the typs as UTC.  This is why I am feeling your "string" solution may be a safer bet as you can then parse the data on the other side.  If you have full control of the front end (e.g. MVC) you could do an "OnDeserialized".

Comment: @ZackJannsen: Sending the offset is *not* the same as sending a time zone. It identifies the instant in time and the local time (aside from calendar system) but it doesn't give any indication about what the local time would be 5 minutes later, when the offset might have changed due to DST transitions etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why either. As Jon suggested a proxy property with the ID is the probably the way to go.

Alternatively, if you actually need to transmit the content of the TimeZoneInfo and support custom zones, you should use a proxy property that wraps `ToSerializedString()` and `FromSerializedString()`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like TimeZoneInfo does not work with WCF very well out-of-the-box.
The workaround can be found here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/f164f185-ae18-4775-a2ff-a814813d262d